# Simplifying Integral based on Symmetry

Tags: calculus, integration

The following integral is to be evaluated over the disc consisting of the interior R of the unit circle, centered at the origin.
I'm trying to simplify the integral using the symmetries of R and the integrand:

$\iint_R {e^x \ dA}$ simplifies to $ 2 \iint_S {e^x \ dA}$ where $S$ is the upper half of $R$.

I'm looking for a reason to understand this simplification.
It is not that e^x is particularly even or odd.

Comment: $$\int\limits_{x=-1}^1 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^x dx\ dy = \pi  I_1(1)$$ where $I_1$ is the Bessel I function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, $e^x$ is not even or odd as a function of $x$, but the bivariate function
$$f(x,y):=e^x$$
is even as a function of $y$: $f(x,-y)=f(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

One way to argue is to apply Fubini's theorem to replace the double integral with an iterated integral, integrating over $y$ first for each $x$, then integrating over $x$. For the inner integral over $y$, you can appeal to even symmetry of both the integrand and the domain (as noted in the comment by @ThomasAndrews).

Comment: And the domain is also invariant under $(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y).$

Comment: So you are telling me in a situation where $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$ I can replace the 2 by 4?

Comment: If both $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$ and $f(x,y)=f(-x,y)$ are true, you can replace integrating over the unit circle with $4$ copies of an integral over the first quadrant of the unit circle.

Comment: Well thanks a lot grand_chat